# Installation of cx_Freeze fails

Tags: cx-freeze

the installation of cx_Freeze fails with the error displayed [in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbHU7.png) below. I would be thankful if someone could guide me through the installation. The installation is attempted on Macbook with M1.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

Same was happening to me, I was using Python version 3.10.3 and the same error was launched. Nevertheless, a collegue with the same Macbook with M1 could install it using Python 3.9.9 I tried and it worked for me. See pictures for confirmation.
[Python version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51WM6.png)
[pip list with cx-Freeze](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upJpe.png)

I use virtual environment in PyCharm taking the python version from my *pyenv* pythons.
To install cx-Freeze I confirmed that it is installing it in the venv using:

```
pip install cx_Freeze
```

And also if set in a requirements.txt using

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I do not know which is the package that uses cx-Freeze is still not supported in python 3.10, but for 3.9.9 it will work ;)